# Compilation error while creating a trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, dblink

> I have created 2 users user1 and user2 and created a emp1 table in user1 and emp2 table in user2.
>   Now I am creating a trigger from user system which has an emp table. This trigger will insert values in emp1 table of user1 and emp2 table of user2 whenever ill enter values in emp table table of user system. But I'm getting compilation errors while creating the following trigger. Can anyone help me with this? Thankyou.

```
create or replace trigger t1 after insert on emp for each row
BEGIN
insert into emp1@Luser1 values(:new.e_id, :new.ename, :new.contact, :new.address);
insert into emp2@Luser2 values(:new.e_id, :new.salary, :new.email);
END
```

Comment: If `user1` and `user2` are schemas, you should apply to them as `user1.emp1`, not `emp1@Luser1`

Comment: Show error, please.